# Why $2\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. exponential?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, independence

How to show that $2\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. exponential with mean $1$?
 Is there a simple way to see this?

Comment: The question as stated is meaningless. What you are most probably asked to show is that $2\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-1$ and $X_1+X_2$ are independent.

Comment: I see, so basically I can reduce $2\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-1$ to $\frac{X_1-X_2}{X_1+X_2}$. But, I still dont see how it is independent from $X_1+X_2$ as the $X_1+X_2$ appears in the denominator of the latter.

Comment: An option would be to compute the joint distribution of $\left(\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2},X_1+X_2\right)$. Any systematic approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
u_1 & = x_1 + x_2 \\[8pt]
u_2 & = \frac{x_1}{x_1+x_2} \\[10pt]
x_1 & = u_1 u_2 \\
x_2 & = u_1(1-u_2) \\[12pt]
du_1\,du_2 = \left| \det\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2} \\[6pt]
\dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1} & \dfrac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}
\end{bmatrix} \right| \, dx_1\,dx_2& = \frac{dx_1\,dx_2}{x_1+x_2} = \frac{dx_1\,dx_2}{u_1} \\[10pt]
u_1\,du_1\,du_2 & = dx_1\,dx_2 \\[15pt]
e^{-x_1} e^{-x_2} \, dx_1\,dx_2 & = e^{-u_1 u_2} e^{-u_1(1-u_2)} u_1\,du_1\,du_2 \\[10pt]
& = \Big( u_1 e^{-u_1} \, du_1 \Big) \Big( du_2 \Big)
\end{align}

So $\dfrac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ is uniformly distributed on the interval from $0$ to $1$, and $X_1+X_2$ has a certain gamma distribution, and they are independent because the density factors as something depending only on $u_1$ times something depending only on $u_2$.

Comment: Can I ask how you got that the ratio is uniformly distributed and that the sum is gamma? Is it from the Jacobian calculation or is that only to prove the independence part?

Comment: @user123276 : It's from the bottom-line expression $\Big( u_1 e^{-u_1}\, du_1\Big) \Big( du_2 \Big)$.  This applies for $u_1\ge0$ and $0\le u_2\le 1$.  If the distribution $f(u_1, u_2)\,du_1\, du_2$ can be factored as $\Big( g(u_1) \,du_1\Big) \Big( h(u_2) \, du_2\Big)$, so that one factor depends only on $u_1$ and the other depends only on $u_2$, then there is some constant $c\ne 0$ such that $cg(u_1)\,du_1$ is the distribution of one of the two random variables and $\dfrac 1 c h(u_2) \, du_2$ is that of the other.  In this case we have just $(1\,du_2)$ for $0\le u_2\le 1. \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and $(1\,du_2)$ for $0\le u_2 \le 1$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1].$ And $(u_1 e^{-u_1}\, du_1)$ for $u_1\ge0$ is a gamma distribution. $\qquad$